Troubleshooting Unexpected Redirection
I'm having an unexpected redirection to my production website from a backup site installed in a subfolder. Despite using a separate database and updating paths, the redirection persists and for checking this I'm using https://redirectchecker.com/. What steps can I take to troubleshoot and identify the source of this redirection issue?
What steps can I take to troubleshoot and identify the source of this redirection issue?
